# Single Table for two windows in openbravo

Tags: openbravo

I have a requirement where I have to use two screens referring  single table in Openbravo with postgresql as database  .I checked out the sales order and purchase order table this functionality is implemented . Their is a column named **IsSOTrx**
which will be set to 'Y' or 'N' conditionally . But how will the Openbravo application knows that this is sales order/purchase order at the time of saving?

Please help

Thanks

Comment: it is via preferences.

Answer (score 0):

**IsSOTrx** is a column in the database table c_order which basically means

> Is Sales Order Transaction

Now if this is true (1) then the order is a sales order otherwise (0) it's a purchase order.

Hope this answers your question. Feel free to ask any other questions.